# Using Redux I am getting the previous state value in the React component,how to get the updated value to the React component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux, I am getting the previous state value in the react component whereas in redux reducers the state gets updated correctly, how I can get the updated value in react component

```
    useEffect((item)=>{
    props.showHome(); 
    },[])

    //I have used onPress which call below function(selectedItem)
    const selectedItem= (item,props) =>{
    props.showList(item); //value is passed to the action
    console.log('In function'+props.listSelected);//listSelected is giving me previous state value}
```

Comment: Can you share more code of the component? It'd help to know how you pass listSelected.

Comment: Yes I will update the code

Comment: Thank you, please share the implementation of `showList`, and the state of `listSelected` in the reducer as well (if that's the state you're watching).

Comment: You will get updated value of `listSelected` during the next render. So you should not expect to get modified values right on the next line of code. What are you trying to actually achieve? This looks like [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I want to use the updated value, as I need to pass this value to the next screen, As here I am not able to get the updated value correctly then sending it to the next screen will show the wrong data on that screen

Comment: get from reduxstore in the nextscreen

Comment: @YuryTarabanko So How I can re-render being on the same screen using useEffect it's not re-rendering when I pass [props.listSelected] to the useEffect

Comment: Since you are using `react-redux` it should rerender your UI automagically when the state is updated. If you are not getting rerender it is likely you have some mutation in your reducer. For example you might be using `someArr.push(newValue)`

Comment: yes i am returning like this ...state, listSelected: action.payload.selected,